# spring-boot banner.text not working when deployed as a WAR File

Tags: spring-boot

Deployment Server : Liberty

`java -jar spring-boot-application.jar` -> Banner is printed as expected

My banner.text

```
Application Name : ${application.title}
Application Version : ${application.version}
Application Formatted Version : ${application.formatted-version}
Spring Boot Version : ${spring-boot-version}
Spring Boot Formatted Version : ${spring-boot.formatted-version}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
${AnsiColor.BRIGHT_RED}  Spring boot banner customization example
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However when I build this jar as webapp

```
mvn install -Pwebapp ( maven-war-plugin)
```

and deploy the WAR on Liberty Server - only `${spring-boot.formatted-version}` is printed. rest are blank.

**Any clues ?**